# MVC controller redirect slow

Tags: java, spring, performance, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I've a Spring MVC controller on which one RequestMapping is calling another one using:

```
return new ModelAndView("redirect:main");
```

Recently, it's taking 5 /6 seconds to redirect. I set the spring-web log level to debug and I can see this:

```
10:15:54,790 AM CET DEBUG DispatcherServlet @ processRequest [991] Successfully completed request
10:16:01,158 AM CET DEBUG DispatcherServlet @ doService [838] DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc' processing GET request for [/AFM/main]
```

Any clue?

Comment: Put a HTTPWatch util on your browser to see when the browser recieved the redirect

Comment: what happened when you use the debug mode ? You could isolate some parts of the code which takes time to process. And then post more informations.

Comment: @vincent Nothing strange.

Comment: You should not build up a ModelAndView. Try only use return a String Object by your method and write return "redirect:main"

Comment: The error was on an Ajax call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was on an ajax call made by a Javascript: the controller completed by it took too much time to render the content. Looking at the network traffic from my browser helped me to find where the issue was.

(I answer to my question because I'm sure in future I'll have same problem)